# Unable to route anything except '/' in Zend framework 2

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework2, zend-server

I am using the Zend Framework 2 with Zend Studio 10 and Zend Server.
The skeleton application run fine, but anything except '/' cannot get routed too, it just returns a "The requested URL was not found on this server"

Here's the module.config, which is almost identical to the skeleton one except I added a controller "Foo" with an action "lol" on the route "/lol" but it does not work.

```
<?php
/**
 * Zend Framework (http://framework.zend.com/)
 *
 * @link      http://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication for the canonical source repository
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2005-2012 Zend Technologies USA Inc. (http://www.zend.com)
 * @license   http://framework.zend.com/license/new-bsd New BSD License
 */

return array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'home' => array(
                'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            // The following is a route to simplify getting started creating
            // new controllers and actions without needing to create a new
            // module. Simply drop new controllers in, and you can access them
            // using the path /application/:controller/:action
            'application' => array(
                'type'    => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/lol',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                        'controller'    => 'Foo',
                        'action'        => 'lol',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                    'default' => array(
                        'type'    => 'Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                            'constraints' => array(
                                'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            ),
                            'defaults' => array(
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'translator' => 'Zend\I18n\Translator\TranslatorServiceFactory',
        ),
    ),
    'translator' => array(
        'locale' => 'en_US',
        'translation_file_patterns' => array(
            array(
                'type'     => 'gettext',
                'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
                'pattern'  => '%s.mo',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Application\Controller\Index' => 'Application\Controller\IndexController',
            'Application\Controller\Foo'   => 'Application\Controller\FooController',

        ),
    ),
    'view_manager' => array(
        'display_not_found_reason' => true,
        'display_exceptions'       => true,
        'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
        'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
        'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
        'template_map' => array(
            'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
            'application/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/application/index/index.phtml',
            'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
            'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
        ),
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Same thing, if I would change the route "/" to "/asdf" (and nothing else) then try to run localhost/Test/asdf rather than localhost/Test/ I would get "URL not found" again.

EDIT: I checked the error log in apache2 and this is what it said:

```
[Mon Jan 07 14:45:58 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/Program Files (x86)/Zend/ZendServer/data/apps/http/__default__/0/Test/1.0.0/public/lol
[Mon Jan 07 14:46:03 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/Program Files (x86)/Zend/ZendServer/data/apps/http/__default__/0/Test/1.0.0/public/lol
```

What could be causing it?

Comment: Did you check .htaccess is parsed (or even able to parse in case you are not using Apache) or the VHOST is configured accordingly?

Comment: How could I do that? (am using Zend Server to deploy on)

Comment: Zend Server is based on Apache and configured to parse .htaccess by default so there should not be any problems from the webservers side. Check if the .htaccess was deployed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it, by configuring the Zend apache2 server and set "AllowOverride None" to "AllowOverride All". I do not know specifically why it helped though, would be glad if someone pointed that out.

Comment: `AllowOveride None` does not permit you to overide any settings via htaccess whereas `AllowOverride All` permits you to override any configuration value (overridable by htaccess). So the RewriteRules could not be set because it was not allowed to do so - They were just ignored.

Comment: can any help me how to allow this AllowOverride All, I did this in the virutal host but it is not successful